# How to insert image on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am using macOS and trying to add an image (png) file on Jupyter Notebook markdown cell, but it keeps generating an error message that they cannot find the png file. I am not sure what is wrong with my following two codes:

`![alt text]("~Users/jj/pythonworkspace/what.is.numpy.png" "What is Numpy?")`
Alternatively,
`<img src="~Users/jj/pythonworkspace/what.is.numpy.png">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using quotations around your path or links. Also i think you meant to have an additional `/` after your home directory or maybe not have `~` at all. The path you're providing isn't following the macOS conventions.

You can test if that path is valid by going into terminal and running

```sh
ls /path/you/are/testing
```

try

```markdown
![What is Numpy?](/Users/jj/pythonworkspace/what.is.numpy.png)
```

Comment: I removed the quotations. Using `ls`, I checked the path and the png.file is there in the directory `/pythonworkspace`, but still producing an error (link is broken).

Comment: As I mentioned earlier about macOS conventions, It's unlikely that you have a `Users` directory sitting under your home directory. Can you try removing ~ and instead use `/Users/jj/pythonworkspace/what.is.numpy.png`. If that works let me know and i can update this answer.

Comment: Great! It works perfect. I didn't realize "~" on the path. Once removed, the problem solved. Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please accept this answer.